# Free public SSH server for testing purposes

Tags: ssh, service, testing

I'm writing an application that makes connections to `SSH` servers. It doesn't need anything specific from the server (except running under GNU/Linux). I need `SSH` servers for running my application tests.

I was wondering, is there some kind of free and open to anyone SSH servers? Maybe it's an idea for a new service :)

Comment: In case you or anybody here is looking to spin up a mock sshd service for testing ssh based utilities / scripts you may use this - https://github.com/kabirbaidhya/fakeserver too.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check out the [Free Shell Accounts](http://shells.red-pill.eu/) list.

Comment: Amazing resource. In fact, I just tried out [Insomnia24/7](http://www.insomnia247.nl/page/shells/index) link and the guys are pretty helpful on the IRC there. Thanks.

Comment: @qre0ct Do you happen to have an Invite Code for Insomnia24/7? Seems like it's invitations only now..

Comment: @qre0ct also I would be glad to receive an invite for Insomnia24/7

Answer (score 47):

http://sdf.org

Have used an account here on and off over the years. Recommended!

Comment: +1 for SDF. I've had a user account there for years.

Comment: +1 but unfortunately it's not actually free if you want to anything useful like gcc, python ..

Comment: Nice, though it doesn't seem to have tools like netcat, telnet etc.

Comment: Well nothing is free. Someone has to pay the bills. And $36 for lifetime access is a good deal.

Comment: When you sign up, it says: your account will expire in 666 days.

Comment: https://www.xshellz.com/ is another good option. you create an account and verify it then you can use `$ ssh username @ shell.xshellz.com`

Comment: I’ve tried SDF and they have a very whacky configuration: psh shell (bash doesn’t seem to be available), `vi` redirects to `pico`, couldn’t even find a way to edit `.ssh/authorized_keys` so I could test public key authentication (even redirecting `echo` doesn’t work as expected). Might work if you just want to test a bare SSH connection with standard settings, but don’t expect too much beyond that.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use virtualization like [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) ? You can setup a running small linux server quickly this way.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, better than need internet connection and free 3rd party ssh accounts, get your own. You can get Virtual Machine (VMWare, VBox, Other) for that, and also, if you have an android mobile you can use SSHDroid (free) instead.

**And don't forget Cygwin** (Linux environment emulation with some package install support). You can set your ssh server built in windows and no need to get entire system (like vm does). A guide (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm)

Regards.