# SSH whitelist 2 addresses

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, unix

We want to block all access to SSH, except for two IP addresses. One address is dynamic, it starts with 124.567.890.xxx where xxx is changing all the time. I read that you can do this by changing `/etc/hosts.allow`? How can we do this?

Answer (score 5):

This should be as trivial as

> sshd : 124.567.890. : allow

Comment: Thanks, and multiple addresses?

Comment: Nvm, found it: sshd: `83.83.83.83 127.0.0.1 83.83.83.84 192.168.1.1`

Comment: In /etc/hosts.deny, you'll need to put in "sshd: ALL", so your combined rule will be deny all, allow X.

Comment: Thanks, and how can I test the security? We only have one IP address right here.

Comment: Is this relevant to your question? http://serverfault.com/questions/185153/free-public-ssh-server-for-testing-purposes